# Hadoop job configuration file specification

Tags: bash, hadoop, cloudera

I have a flow of ~10 Hadoop jobs. I have sequence of XML files that configure these jobs for instance:

```
-conf /path/on/my/local/system/start-conf.xml
-conf /path/on/my/local/system/job-1-conf.xml
-conf /path/on/my/local/system/job-2-conf.xml
-conf /path/on/my/local/system/job-i-conf.xml
...
-conf /path/on/my/local/system/job-10-conf.xml
```

Let's assume I have class which is used for running jobs named "com.my.project.RunClass"
Let's assume I run my jobs with this command:

```
hadoop jar /path/to/project.jar com.my.project.RunClass -conf /path/on/my/local/system/start-conf.xml
```

I would like to replace segment "/path/on/my/local/system" with some placeholder for example: ${root.conf.dir}, so that I could run jobs with something like:

```
hadoop jar /path/to/project.jar com.my.project.RunClass -conf ${root.conf.dir}/job-1-conf.xml -Droot.conf.dir=/path/on/my/local/system
```

Is this possible with any versions of Hadoop? I am using Cloudera distro, and it seems like it fails each time.

Comment: There was no Hadoop exception - it would silently continue, and then when I miss properties in my business code, it would throw business exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about bash 4.*, but older bashes don't support vars names with '.'s in them.

Try

```
root_conf_dir="/path/on/my/local/system"
hadoop jar /path/to/project.jar com.my.project.RunClass \
    -conf "${root_conf_dir}"/job-1-conf.xml \
    -Droot.conf.dir="${root_conf_dir}"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It actually turned out to be problem with "." and not-escaped "$" in my version of CentOS linux (GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)